# Almost random restarts/crashes on iPhone WebGL/js web app

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, web-applications

I am working on an web app that needs to run both on Android and iPhone.
There are all sort of reasons why such an app would crash.
One of them being memory, others maybe wrong access to URL or even run time errors in js.

My biggest issue now, is that whenever the iPhone crash, it just restarts. It reports no error, no crash report, no log, no nothing.

It makes it extremely difficult to guess what is the reason for the web app to crash.
Is there something I need to enable on iPhone to see the errors?
Maybe some code in js?

Thanks.

Comment: It's common for apps that run out of memory to give no other info. They can't generate an error message as that would require memory. My only suggestion is bisect your app. Pull out 50% of the features until it stops crashing. Try to narrow down which specific feature is causing the crash. Another suggestion would be to run it in desktop safari and use the debugging tools to watch memory.

Comment: Safari doesn't seem to give me also a good indication how much memory I use. BTW, on Android I do get an error when there is not enough memory for an operation. Android also show me all the allocated objects in js. Safari show me the total memory, and it doesn't seem to make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the errors are displayed in a different place than the log.
I assumed errors would appear the same place as the log, in the safari inspector. But You actually need to click the red error sign to see the errors.

The errors I saw in my case is that it was binding a disposed texture and program.
This might be because I Teardown the assets but the mesh is still in the THREE.js scene, so the next time it renders, it's missing those assets.